# Element API: Group Categories by Groups

Tags: categories, plugin-elementapi

I want to use the Element API to output a hierarchical JSON list of categories grouped by category group. For example:

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Meal Type",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 284,
                    "title": "Dinner"
                },
                {
                    "id": 285,
                    "title": "Breakfast"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Dietary Restrictions",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 291,
                    "title": "Vegan"
                },
                {
                    "id": 292,
                    "title": "Gluten Free"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do it within the confines of the element transformer because I can't step outside of it to run some grouping logic before outputting the result. If there was some way of knowing when I've reached the end of the transformer loop then I could delay the return statement until the end of the list:

```
'categories.json' => function() {
    $catGroups = array();
    return [
        'elementType' => Category::class,
        'criteria' => [
            'group' => ['meal','diet'],
            'level' => 1,
            'orderBy' => 'groupId,title'
        ],
        'resourceKey' => 'groups',
        'paginate' => false,
        'transformer' => function(Category $cat) use (&$catGroups) {
            $groupExists = false;
            
            // look for existing group, add category
            // to it if found, and exit
            foreach($catGroups as $key => $group) {
                if( $group['id'] == $cat->group->id ) {
                    $catGroups[$key]['categories'][] = [
                        'id' => $cat->id,
                        'title' => $cat->title
                    ];
                    $groupExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if group doesn't already exist,
            // create it
            if(!$groupExists) {
                $categories = [
                    'id' => $cat->id,
                    'title' => $cat->title
                ];
                $catGroups[] = [
                    'id' => $cat->group->id,
                    'name' => $cat->group->name,
                    'categories' => [$categories] 
                ];
            }

            // output entire array on final loop
            if($transformer->index == $transformer->total) {
                    return $catGroups;
            }
            return false;
        },
        'pretty' => true
    ];
},
```

Is this possible? Maybe using pagination somehow?